# RxJS and repeated events

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs

I am new to RxJs in general but am investigating a bug in some React code in which, upon an unrelated action, an old event seems to be emitted and rendered to a display error. Think if you had two buttons that generated two messages somewhere on screen, and clicking one button was showing the message for the other button.

Being new to RxJs I'm not positive where the problem lays. I don't see a single `ReplaySubject` in the code, only `Obserable`s, `Subject`s, and `BehaviourSubject`s. So this is either misuse of an RxJs feature or just some bad logic somewhere.

Anyway I found the code with the related `Observable` and I'm not quite sure what this person was trying to accomplish here. I have read up on `combineLatest`, `map`, and `pipe`, but this looks like pointless code to me. Could it also be somehow re-emitting old events? I don't see dynamic subscriptions anywhere, especially in this case.

Tldr I don't understand the intent of this code.

```
export interface IFeedback {
  id: number
  text: string
}

export interface IFeedbackMessages {
  message: IFeedback | undefined
}

feedback$ = new BehaviorSubject<IFeedback | undefined>(undefined)

feedbackNotifs$: Observable<IFeedbackMessages> = combineLatest([
  feedback$
]).pipe(
  map(([feedback]) => ({
    feedback
  })
))
```

---

I also found this which maybe be an issue. In the React component that displays this message, am I wrong but does it look like each time this thing renders it subscribes and then unsubscribes to the above Subject?

```
const FeedbackDisplay: React.FC () => {
   
  const [feedbackNotifications, setFeedbackNotifications] = React.useState<IFeedbackMessages>()
  React.useEffect(() =>
  {
    const sub = notification$.subscribe(setFeedbackNotifications)
    return () => sub?.unsubscribe()
  }, [notifications$])

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could it also be somehow re-emitting old events?

Yes, it probably is. `BehaviorSubject` has the unique property of immediately emitting the last value pushed to it as soon as you subscribe to it.

It's great when you want to model some persistent state value, and it's not good for events whose actual moment of occurrence is key. It sounds like the feedback messages you're working with fall into the second category, in which case `Subject` is probably a better choice.

> does it look like each time this thing renders it subscribes and then unsubscribes to the above Subject?

Not exactly. `useEffect` accepts a callback, and within that callback you can optionally return a "cleanup" function. React will hang onto that function until the effect is triggered again, then it calls it to clean things up (which in this case consists of closing out the subscription) to make room for the next effect.

So in this case, the unsubscribe will only happen when the component is rendered with a new value for `notifications$`. Also worth pointing out that notifications$ will only change if it's either passed as a prop or created within the component function. If it's defined outside the function (imported from another file for example), you don't need to (and in fact should not) put it into `useEffect`'s dependency array.

Comment: `notifications$` is created at the top of this component but is the result of a function call. That function returns `notifications$` which is a `React.useContext`. I cannot understand what that implies.

Comment: For the purposes of the answer, it should be treated as something that can change and trigger re-renders in the process, meaning it does belong in the dependency array. Nonetheless, the rest of the answer stands. More on [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in React.